# Javascript properties and methods

Tags: javascript, dom, methods, properties

I'm just a beginner learning how to use javascript by manipulating the DOM and I was just wondering if there was a way to see a reference for all methods and properties. Something like what jquery provides for its methods on the jquery website. Is there some way I can find a list of all of them? I think I saw a list of methods on the javascript console, but I don't know how to access them. Thanks.

Comment: This is a good resource https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For JavaScript, there's [the specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) but it's fairly heavy going. There's also [MDN's JavaScript pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) which are a *lot* more accessible and generally accurate (but note that some of the shims/polyfill code you find in MDN — as opposed to the reference material — for things that not all browsers have are *extremely* variable quality community-contributed content — but that's a side issue). Web searches will also pop up links to w3schools, which I would not recommend.

For the DOM (which is an entirely separate thing), there are [the various DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) (probably best to start with [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) and then branch out); [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), which increasingly has DOM stuff in it as well, particularly in the [web application APIs section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#webappapis); and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/API).